# How can delete the single ones in a chemical formula using regex?

Tags: regex, matlab

If I have a chemical formula like this `C6H12Ne1O6P1R1` (this is what ppl sent me). how can I get this result `C6H12NeO6PR` with matlab. (be aware that I dont want to delete the 1 in the H12 only in the ones in Ne1, P1 and R1)

So far i have tried `regexprep('C6H12Ne1O6P1R1', '[a-zA-Z](1)[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z](1)$', '')` but it removes more than I want.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new on this. I tried this but delete more things that I want regexprep('C6H12Ne1O6P1R1', '[a-zA-Z](1)[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z](1)$', '')

Comment: I don't think matlab supports lookbehinds, so you can try [`([2-9]|\d{2,})|1` replace with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/zr27vY/2)

Comment: @ctwheels [it does](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html)

Comment: @excaza thanks! Then [`(?<!\d)1(?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/zr27vY/3) may be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@excaza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2748311/excaza) for pointing out that [matlab does support lookbehinds](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html). Since it does support these, the following may be used to replace all individual `1`'s from your string. [See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/zr27vY/3)

```
(?<!\d)1(?!\d)
```

- `(?<!\d)` Negative lookbehind ensuring what precedes is not a digit
- `1` Match this literally
- `(?!\d)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows is not a digit

Result: `C6H12NeO6PR`